# Can not use hibernate mapping XMLType column

Tags: hibernate, jboss, seam, xmltype

I'm building project using JBoss Seam, Hibernate 3.5.6, Oracle 11g.
I generated table (with column "XML_DATA_INPUT"). After generating, there are Quotation.java, QuotationList.java, QuotationHome.java.
here Quotation.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUOTATION")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqQuotationId", sequenceName = "SEQ_QUOTATION_ID", allocationSize = 1)
public class Quotation implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1815510016894007629L;

    private Long id;
    private String code;

    private Long userId;

    private Clob xmlDataInput;
        ......

    @Column(name = "XML_DATA_INPUT")    
    public Clob getXmlDataInput() {
        return this.xmlDataInput;
    }

    public void setXmlDataInput(Clob xmlDataInput) {
        this.xmlDataInput = xmlDataInput;
    }
        .....
```

after project is built. there is an error

```
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: quotationList
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2170)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2024)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1986)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:50)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.resolveBase(SeamELResolver.java:148)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.getValue(SeamELResolver.java:51)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:63)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:284)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:154)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:190)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:166)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.renderkit.DecorateRendererBase.doEncodeChildren(DecorateRendererBase.java:152)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:92)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.SimpleToggleControlTemplate.doEncodeChildren(SimpleToggleControlTemplate.java:301)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.SimpleToggleControlTemplate.doEncodeChildren(SimpleToggleControlTemplate.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.SimpleTogglePanelRenderer.encodeChildren(SimpleTogglePanelRenderer.java:188)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:151)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: exception invoking: getEntityManager
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:154)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.unwrap(Component.java:2301)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2044)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1986)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1975)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.Controller.getComponentInstance(Controller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.PersistenceController.getPersistenceContext(PersistenceController.java:20)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery.getEntityManager(EntityQuery.java:159)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityQuery.validate(EntityQuery.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:61)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at vn.com.unit.kliq.session.quotation.QuotationList_$$_javassist_seam_2.validate(QuotationList_$$_javassist_seam_2.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2198)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2158)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/web/tomcat/service/WebCtxLoader$ENCLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/persistence/LockModeType"
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at $Proxy490.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:588)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.PersistenceProvider.proxyEntityManager(PersistenceProvider.java:220)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernatePersistenceProvider.proxyEntityManager(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:325)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.initEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:81)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:108)
```

I tried many same topics. But i never have solved the problem.
please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this class as a seam component you should add @Name(name) annotation at the beginning of the class so seam can understand this class is a seam component.